# Crash accessing RoomDatabase from BackgroundService or JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-intent, android-room, intentservice, background-service

I am trying to access the `RoomDatabase` from the context of `Service`/`IntentService` extended background service class and from JobScheduler based JobService extended class.

Since both are service class, so both are itself are context. But RoomDatabase is not getting initialized by that context. And the `getApplicationContext()` of these classes is also null.

The requirement is, when the application is in background (killed it's process from `multi-tasking` also), then Network based or Location based background service triggers will wants to access `RoomDatabase` and causing it to crash.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:714)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$JournalMode.resolve(RoomDatabase.java:388)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:628)
```

One example of implementation is :

```
internal class JobSchedulerService:JobService() {

    private lateinit var logger:Logger
    private lateinit var appContext:Context

    override fun onCreate() {
        this.appContext = this@JobSchedulerService

        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.w("TAG","JobSchedulerService: onStartJob: $params context:$this")

        logger = Logger(this.appContext)
        logger.log(logInfo = "JobSchedulerService: onStartJob: $params")

        if (params!!.jobId == EVENT_TYPE.LOCATION_CHANGE.value) {
            val intent = Intent(this, BackgroundService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("JobSchedulerService: eventType", EVENT_TYPE.LOCATION_CHANGE.value)
            // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
            startService(intent)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {

        logger = Logger(this.appContext)
        logger.log(logInfo = "JobSchedulerService: onStopJob: $params")
        return true
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {

        logger = Logger(this.appContext)
        logger.log(logInfo = "JobSchedulerService: low memory trigged")
        super.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

another service class example is:

```
class NetworkJobService:JobService() {

    private lateinit var logger: Logger
    private lateinit var appContext: Context
    private val connectivityManager:ConnectivityManager by lazy { this.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager }

    private val wifiManager by lazy {
        this@NetworkJobService.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    }
    private val networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback by lazy {
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network?, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities?) {
                super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)

                val intent = Intent(this@NetworkJobService, BackgroundService::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("eventType", EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value)
                // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
                this@NetworkJobService.startService(intent)

            }

            override fun onLinkPropertiesChanged(network: Network?, linkProperties: LinkProperties?) {
                super.onLinkPropertiesChanged(network, linkProperties)

                val intent = Intent(this@NetworkJobService, BackgroundService::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("eventType", EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value)
                // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
                this@NetworkJobService.startService(intent)

            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
                super.onLost(network)

                val intent = Intent(this@NetworkJobService, BackgroundService::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("eventType", EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value)
                // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
                this@NetworkJobService.startService(intent)

            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable()

                val intent = Intent(this@NetworkJobService, BackgroundService::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("eventType", EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value)
                // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
                this@NetworkJobService.startService(intent)

            }

            override fun onLosing(network: Network?, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)

                val intent = Intent(this@NetworkJobService, BackgroundService::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("eventType", EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value)
                // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
                this@NetworkJobService.startService(intent)

            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        this.appContext = this@NetworkJobService
        super.onCreate()
    }
    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        logger = Logger(this.appContext)
        logger.log(logInfo = "NetworkJobService: onStartJob: $params")

        if (params!!.jobId == EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value){
            val intent = Intent(this.appContext, BackgroundService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("eventType", EVENT_TYPE.NETWORK_CHANGE.value)
            // this will call BackgroundService onHandle fun
            startService(intent)
        }
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest.Builder().build(), networkCallback)
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        logger = Logger(this.appContext)
        logger.log(logInfo = "NetworkJobService: onStopJob: $params")
        return true
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        logger = Logger(this.appContext)
        logger.log(logInfo = "NetworkJobService: low memory trigged")
        super.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

And then Logger is having singleton db instance

```
internal class Logger {

    internal var appContext: Context

    internal var database: MobileSecurityDatabase

    internal constructor(context:Context) {
        appContext = context
        database = MobileSecurityDatabase.getInstance(appContext)
    }


    fun log(logInfo:String){

        runBlocking {
            launch(Dispatchers.Default){
                val logTime = Date().time
                val cipher:Cipher = Utils.generateCipher(logTime)
                val sealedObject = SealedObject(appId + " : " + logInfo, cipher)

                Log.w("logger", appId!! + " : " + logInfo)
                val byteArray = Utils.sealedObjectStream(sealedObject)
                if (byteArray != null)  {
                    val logData = LogData(logTime, byteArray)
                    database.logDao().insertLog(logData = logData)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In last comes RoomPersistence class which is singleton:

```
@Database(entities = [LogData::class, UserData::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MobileSecurityDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun logDao(): LogDao

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao


    companion object : SingletonHolder<MobileSecurityDatabase, Context>({ it: Context ->

        Room.databaseBuilder(it, MobileSecurityDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
                .addCallback(object: RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase){                       
                    }

                    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onOpen(db)
                    }
                })
                .build()
    })
}
```

After making the changes suggested in answers for scope of context. I have started getting exception when my app is closed and in locked state. I unlocked the app and launched some other app.

```
10-06 22:20:00.086 886-886/? D/SFPerfTracer:        layers: (4:12) (StrictModeFlash#0 (0xadcc8000): 0:146)* (StatusBar#0 (0xade3c000): 3:69585) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xade45000): 0:3760) (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xadb1e000): 0:867)* (Sprite#0 (0xade43000): 0:12)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xadb3b000): 0:91)* (NavigationBar#0 (0xadb34000): 0:2770) (Splash Screen android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication#0 (0xadbda000): 0:16)- (android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication.MainActivity#0 (0xadb31000): 0:29)- (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#0 (0xadbda000): 0:28)- (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#1 (0xafedd000): 0:16)- (com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity#0 (0xadb31000): 25:62) 
10-06 22:29:50.104 886-886/? D/SFPerfTracer:        layers: (3:11) (StrictModeFlash#0 (0xadcc8000): 0:146)* (StatusBar#0 (0xade3c000): 0:69860) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xade45000): 0:3761)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xadb1e000): 0:867)* (Sprite#0 (0xade43000): 0:12)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xadb3b000): 0:93)* (NavigationBar#0 (0xadb34000): 12:2824) (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#0 (0xafedd000): 0:26)* (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#1 (0xadbda000): 0:58)* (Splash Screen android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication#0 (0xadb72000): 2:27) (android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication.MainActivity#0 (0xad606000): 3:3)* 
10-06 22:29:59.630 886-886/? D/SFPerfTracer:        layers: (4:13) (StrictModeFlash#0 (0xadcc8000): 0:146)* (StatusBar#0 (0xade3c000): 1:69867) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xade45000): 0:3762) (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xadb1e000): 0:867)* (Sprite#0 (0xade43000): 0:12)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xadb3b000): 0:93)* (NavigationBar#0 (0xadb34000): 2:2894) (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#0 (0xafedd000): 0:26)- (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#1 (0xadbda000): 0:58)- (Splash Screen android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication#0 (0xadb72000): 0:37)- (android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication.MainActivity#0 (0xad606000): 0:27)- (com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity#0 (0xadb72000): 35:47) (thumbnail anim#0 (0xafedd000): 0:23)- 
10-06 22:40:32.708 29528-29528/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication, PID: 29528
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{aecac5d u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:112)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{aecac5d u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1536)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1492)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService.onStartJob(NetworkJobService.kt:90)
        at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:71)
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
10-06 22:41:08.215 29930-29930/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication, PID: 29930
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6b2ae65 u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:112)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6b2ae65 u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1536)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1492)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService.onStartJob(NetworkJobService.kt:90)
        at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:71)
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
10-06 22:42:08.919 30314-30314/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication, PID: 30314
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{a8df8a3 u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:112)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{a8df8a3 u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1536)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1492)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService.onStartJob(NetworkJobService.kt:90)
        at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:71)
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
10-06 22:42:08.951 1768-3051/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.JobSchedulerService in 1000ms
    Scheduling restart of crashed service android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService in 11000ms
10-06 22:45:07.604 1768-1768/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 30522:android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/u0a273 for service android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService
10-06 22:45:08.200 1768-4078/? W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) } to android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService from pid=30522 uid=10273 pkg=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication
10-06 22:45:08.205 30522-30522/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication, PID: 30522
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{ed0b59a u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:112)
        ...
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{ed0b59a u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        ....
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService.onStartJob(NetworkJobService.kt:90)
        at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:71)
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
        ...
10-06 22:45:08.241 1768-4082/? I/ActivityManager: Process android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication (pid 30522) has died: vis  TRN
10-06 22:45:49.314 1768-1930/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{35e64ad u0 android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService}
```

And then got crash pop up on my device.
 The exception at that time was:

```
10-06 22:46:18.260 1768-2052/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/.MainActivity,cp,ca,27875
10-06 22:46:20.228 886-886/? D/SFPerfTracer:        layers: (4:11) (StrictModeFlash#0 (0xadcc8000): 0:149)* (StatusBar#0 (0xade3c000): 2:70759) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xade45000): 0:3771) (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xadb1e000): 0:867)* (Sprite#0 (0xade43000): 0:12)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xadb3b000): 0:109)* (NavigationBar#0 (0xadb34000): 4:3666) (AOD#0 (0xade21000): 0:81)- (android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication.MainActivity#0 (0xadbd5000): 0:30)- (com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity#0 (0xafedd000): 24:35) (thumbnail anim#0 (0xade21000): 0:22)- 
10-06 22:46:20.559 30861-30861/? E/ActivityThread: Activity android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.BatteryReciever@f325fba that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.BatteryReciever@f325fba that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1360)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1141)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1436)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1397)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1385)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:609)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.Services.startJob(Services.kt:72)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.LocationBackgroundService.startLocationChange(LocationBackgroundService.kt:126)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.LocationBackgroundService$onCreate$1.onLocationChanged(LocationBackgroundService.kt:46)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:292)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
10-06 22:46:20.573 1768-2529/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 30861:android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/u0a273 (adj 1001): remove task
10-06 22:46:20.600 1768-3054/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.LocationBackgroundService in 1000ms
10-06 22:46:21.610 1768-1930/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 31887:android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/u0a273 for service android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.LocationBackgroundService
10-06 22:46:21.673 1768-3492/? W/ActivityManager: Stopping service due to app idle: u0a273 -29s581ms android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.LocationBackgroundService
10-06 22:46:22.057 1768-4081/? W/ActivityManager: Service done with onDestroy, but executeNesting=2: ServiceRecord{e29b4af u0 android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.LocationBackgroundService}
10-06 22:49:37.973 1768-2376/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 31887:android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/u0a273 (adj 906): empty #17
10-06 22:59:21.333 1768-1768/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4425:android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/u0a273 for service android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.JobSchedulerService
10-06 22:59:21.791 4425-4425/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-06 22:59:21.825 4425-4425/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication W/TAG: JobSchedulerService: onStartJob: android.app.job.JobParameters@6c9edb4 context:android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.JobSchedulerService@79f3ddd
10-06 22:59:21.890 4425-4467/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication W/logger: unknown : JobSchedulerService: onStartJob: android.app.job.JobParameters@6c9edb4
10-06 22:59:21.943 4425-4467/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication W/logger: unknown : NetworkJobService: onStartJob: android.app.job.JobParameters@8172c49
10-06 22:59:21.950 1768-3501/? W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) } to android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService from pid=4425 uid=10273 pkg=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication
10-06 22:59:21.951 4425-4425/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication E/JobServiceEngine: Error while executing job: 4002
10-06 22:59:21.951 4425-4425/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-06 22:59:21.955 4425-4425/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication, PID: 4425
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{9874a04 u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:112)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.backgroundservices.BackgroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{9874a04 u0a273 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1536)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1492)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
        at android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService.onStartJob(NetworkJobService.kt:90)
        at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:71)
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
10-06 22:59:21.969 1768-1931/? I/ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication u0
10-06 22:59:29.832 1768-1768/? W/JobServiceContext: No response from client for onStartJob c8cbe13 #u0a273/4002 android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication/android.thakur.com.mobilesecurity.services.jobs.NetworkJobService
10-06 22:59:30.962 886-886/? D/SFPerfTracer:        layers: (6:10) (StrictModeFlash#0 (0xadcc8000): 0:151)* (StatusBar#0 (0xade3c000): 1:71776) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xade45000): 0:3779) (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xadb1e000): 0:877) (Sprite#0 (0xade43000): 0:12)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xadb3b000): 0:109)* (NavigationBar#0 (0xadb34000): 0:3745) (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#0 (0xafedd000): 0:16)* (com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#1 (0xadb31000): 0:46) (Application Error: android.thakur.com.mobilesecurityapplication#0 (0xadb28000): 0:14)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], showing where and how you are attempting to initialize the `RoomDatabase`.

Comment: please refer to example in github : https://github.com/ankitthakur/MobileSecurity-Android. It is working fine in normal scenario, but is crashing in services class : https://github.com/ankitthakur/MobileSecurity-Android/tree/master/mobilesecurity/src/main/java/android/thakur/com/mobilesecurity/services/jobs